# phantomjs and ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I'm playing a bit with phantomjs and coffeescript, what I want to achieve after visiting a site which in his page has already jquery is to fire some ajax get requests which should
return me the data. I've played a bit with firefox console and works really nice. Unfortunately phantomjs doesn return nothing and I don't know why.

```
page = require('webpage').create()
system = require 'system'

url = 'http://www.testpage.com'
#page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js")
page.open url,
  (status) ->
    if status isnt 'success'
      console.log 'uanble to acces the netzwprk'
    else
      results = page.evaluate ->
        all = []
        list = $(".navigation .main")
        for item in list
          all.push(item.href)
        #return all
          $.get item.href, (data,status) ->
            console.log data.toSource()

      #console.log results.join('\n')
    phantom.exit()
```

thks. for help volk.

xaver

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have to wait for phantomjs to finish loading the page.  you can see this for some hints: https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=265